# Definition of effective enumerability and empty set

Tags: logic, definition, computability

Let $S$ be a set. We say that $S$ is effectively enumerable iff (by definition) there exists a function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ which has $S$ as codomain. My question is: is the empty set an effectively enumerable set by this definition? The sentence

for all $x$ in $S$: $x \in \mathrm{cod}(f)$

is equivalent to

there is not $x$ in $S$: $x \notin \mathrm{cod}(f)$,

and this last one is obvious if $S=\emptyset$. So I believe that the statement

> There exists a function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that there is not $x$ in $S$: $x \notin \mathrm{cod}(f)$

is trivially satisfied for any $f$, so empty set is effectively enumerable. Am I right?

Comment: Your definition of "effectively enumerable" needs the restriction that the function be computable.

Comment: Don't you want to require something on the function besides having codomain $S$ (e.g. computable function)

Comment: Your argument only shows that $\emptyset$ is a subset of cod(f).

Answer (score 5):

Since this question was tagged as computability, I am assuming that in the definition of effectively enumerable, the function $f : \omega \rightarrow \omega$ is a total computable function.

In computability theory, the usual definition of a computably enumerable (c.e.) set is the domain of a partial computable function.

It can be shown by so called "Listing Theorem" that a set $A$ is c.e. if and only if $A = \emptyset$ or $A$ is the range of a total computable function.

So the $\emptyset$ is a c.e. set. However, it is not the range of any total computable function $f: \omega \rightarrow \omega$, since the range of such function can not be empty. Therefore, the "Listing Theorem" characterization of c.e. sets separately includes the $\emptyset$ as a c.e. set. (Of course, $\emptyset$ is c.e. if you use the original definition of being the domain of a partial computable function.)

Intuitively, computable set are those that whose membership can be computed, i.e. there is an algorithm that halt on *all* inputs and tells you correctly the membership. Computably enumerable sets are those that possess that an algorithm that will eventually halt if $n \in A$ and not halt if $n \notin A$. So in some sense, the definition using domain of partial computable functions adhere more closely to this intuition than "listable" since $\emptyset$ does not quite work. Of course, no one would deny that $\emptyset$ is computable, and every computable set should be c.e.