# How we can prove that the logical result of a set is effectively enumerable?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> How we can prove that the logical result of $\{(p_i \vee $~ $p_{i+1}$$) $$:
> i \in  \mathbb{N} \}$ is effectively enumerable ?

Update: as one user requests, I add my method. I use truth table for check the result but I'm sure there is a flaw and other method must be used.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: okey @user37238 thanks so much. thanks for your welcome, really I get stuck in how method must be used. there is a lemma in my note, but without proof.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204879/completness-and-set-of-result-of-one-set/1206510#1206510

Comment: This has been asked before for previous questions you have asked: please do not over-tag your questions. This question is not related to first-order logic, so that tag should not be included. What does need to be added is a better description of the question; as it stands the question is not understandable to me. What is the "logical result of a set"? @Mikhaeil Minaoli

Comment: @Sebastian this is a similar link, but what do u mean by "The last can be checked by truth tables." the mentioned link hasn't answer to my question !?

Comment: I voted to close this question for a different reason, but there is an answer to this question in Sebastian's answer to the other one (if "logical result" means "logical consequences"), so closing as a duplicate appears to be reasonable.

Comment: @Mikhaeil Minaoli: many of the questions you have asked could be improved. Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question for some suggestions. In general, you should always indicate where you encountered the question and what you have already tried. In this case, the solution is somewhat trivial -- the set of consequences of any r.e. set of formulas is again r.e. - which makes the motivation for the question more confusing.

Comment: @CarlMummert I have no asked question, I just ask this one as my first question. are you wrong with me? ?

Comment: thanks from your kind note, the set of consequences of any r.e. set of formulas is again r.e. is not good, because the question say the set of consequences of any r.e. set of formulas is effectively enumerable ? is there any thing different? thanks @CarlMummert

Comment: @CarlMummert would you please describe it for me?

Comment: I read it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161122/definition-of-effective-enumerability-and-empty-set  @CarlMummert but couldn't get the point.

Comment: your answer about set of consequence is wrong, @Sebastian on that link